# How do I fill the current selection with color?

Tags: gimp

I remember there's some option allow you to fill current selection with colors , but I couldn't find it anymore

Comment: Paint in selection creates a shadow around the boundary! How can one get rid of that?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

All you must do in GIMP is use the [Fill Bucket](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-bucket-fill.html) tool, holding down shift will toggle between the 'fill similar color' and 'fill whole selection' options.

Comment: Paint in selection creates a shadow around the boundary! How can one get rid of that?

Comment: FYI, in order for the Bucket Fill gadget to work correctly, you need to ensure that the proper layer is selected...

Comment: After I select a rectangle selection with the rect select tool, when I click on Bucket Fill tool, my selection disappears...! So :\ I cannot fill it.

Answer (score 10):

You can fill the current selection with either the foreground color or the background color from the Edit menu. `Ctrl + ,` and `Ctrl + .` respectively on the keyboard.

Comment: This is the real accepted answer.

Answer (score 5):

Just change the foreground or background color to the color of your choice and then just drag it to your image, any part will do because whenever there is a selection on an image, any action done on the image is assumed to be on the selection. Dragging the color to any part of your image, selected or not, will fill the selection with that color.